# Multi-cloud swarm cluster service discovery using DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, networking, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I've managed to create a multi-cloud swarm cluster, with a leader node on GCP and a worker node on AWS. Deployment is running fine, but the only issue I've stumbled upon is the service discovery using DNS names.

For example, I have deployed a service called **db** on the leader node (GCP) and an **app** service on the worker node (AWS). They are using an overlay network defined as such:

```yml
networks:
  internal:
    attachable: true
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.0.69.0/24
```

On the GCP network, I've opened the following ports:

- **2377** TCP port for cluster management communications;
- **7946** TCP&UDP ports for communication among nodes;
- **4789** for overlay network traffic.

On the AWS network, I've opened the following ports:

- **7946** TCP&UDP ports for communication among nodes;
- **4789** for overlay network traffic.

(source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/)

The **db** container gets the IP `10.0.69.8` and the **app** container gets the IP `10.0.69.21`. Containers are not able to ping each other, nor resolve the *db* and *app* DNS names. All I get is `Destination Host Unreachable` when I try to ping the other one.

Is my approach sketchy and I'm missing something? Or am I breaking something fundamental?
Does a multi-cloud swarm cluster require already connected networks? And if so, is a VPN between GCP and AWS networks the only way?

Comment: If you have some nodes in AWS and some in GCP they have to talk to each other so VPN looks like only solution. But I don't understand first phrase "0


I've managed to create a multi-cloud swarm cluster, with a leader node on GCP and a worker node on AWS. Deployment is running fine, but the only issue I've stumbled upon is the service discovery using DNS names." - can you explain - can both clouds talk to each other or no ??? Please privde more details about your setup.

Comment: I'm sorry for being too vague in describing the setup. I've created two nodes, one on GCP and one on AWS. Both of them have public IP addresses. I've opened the ports (described in the main post) on both of them. They can talk to each other, via the public Internet, but they are not on the same subnet. I managed to join with the AWS node to the swarm created by the GCP node, using the public IP address. I deployed on this swarm a couple of services, and they are being deployed successfully on both of them. But a container deployed to a node can't talk to a container deployed to the other.

Comment: even though they are both deployed on the same docker overlay network. Containers from the same node can talk to each other, but container across nodes can't.

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966243/docker-swarm-can-not-communicate-with-other-nodes-on-custom-overlay-network

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create one swarm (cluster) in two different clouds [you have to use VPN](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to) - to the best of my knowledge there's no way around it.

As you see the nodes can communicate using public IP's [but the containers cannot](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) (they can only use internal IP's) and your GCP & AWS networks aren't connected.

> "Services or containers can only communicate across networks they are each connected to."

In such case DNS resolving isn't the issue here. Just the effect.

When you connect networks make sure the IP's of the GCP and AWS subnets aren't overlapping - otherwise you may face another issue and have to resort using double-NAT or some other very overcomplicated solutions.

It's best to keep it simple (read - better to use just one cloud) and keep your cluster there.

Comment: Before "Services or containers can only communicate across networks they are each connected to." it says that "Services or containers can be connected to more than one network at a time.". I'm my opinion, I think refers to docker networks, not host-specific networks. I couldn't find any references on overlay networks requiring nodes to be on the same subnet.

Comment: Were you able to figure out some solution maybe ?

Comment: Nope, still looking for a solution.